# fetching emails using exchangelib by message_id

Tags: python, exchange-server, exchangelib

I am maintaining an application using exchangelib. I need to be able to move emails to different folders, which is perfectly possible using exchangelib. However, I should give the possibility to my clients to do the same manually. What I want to be able to do is to see what email is moved to what folder later. So I need a tracking id for emails. So may questions are:

1. Does the `message_id` field serve as this unique identifier?
2. It seems it is not possible to fetch emails in bulk using `message_id`. What is the best practice for this? I can fetch emails using `item_id` and `changekey`, by calling `account.fetch` however, they change as the user moves email around different folders, while the `message_id` does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re. 1, it seems you already found out that `message_id` is left untouched when an item is moved. I can't find any hard documentation from EWS regarding this fact, so make sure to do extensive testing.

Re. 2, it's true that you can only use `account.fetch` with `item_id` values. However, there are some things to note:

1. When you call `item.move()`, `item.item_id` and `item.changekey` attributes are updated to the new location, which you could store for a future bulk operation. See https://github.com/ecederstrand/exchangelib/blob/3a1def29951d26c8a1b7021c7582c3d118181140/exchangelib/items.py#L365
2. You can still fetch in bulk by `message_id` by first translating the `message_id` to an `item_id`. This does a `FindItem` call and then a `GetItem` call:

---

```
item_ids = account.inbox.filter(message_id__in=<your_message_ids>) \
    .values_list('item_id', 'changekey')
bulk_items = account.fetch(item_ids)
```

You probably want to chunk `<your_message_ids>` items so the `__in` filter does not get extremely large.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you answers. That seems to solve the problem. 
Just a related question. Is there any possibility to force `filter()` function, search recursively inside folders? By default it just gos one level deep.

Comment: Yes. The search API also works on collections of folders, e.g. `account.inbox.children.filter()` or `account.inbox.root.glob('foo*').filter()`. See the bottom of the https://github.com/ecederstrand/exchangelib#searching section.

Comment: @ErikCederstrand hello Erik.. How to get all mail property names list? like `importance`, `hasattachments` etc.. do we get a complete list of mail property names from exchangelib?

Comment: The easiest method is probably `for f in Message.FIELDS: print(f.name)`. See also https://ecederstrand.github.io/exchangelib/exchangelib/items/message.html